# how to append text from editable div to textarea jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append text from an editable `div` to a `textarea`. I'm using TinyMCE WYSIWYG with the `textarea`.

```js
$('#insert').click(function() {
  // var contentArea =
  var modalContent = $('#mdoalTextArea').text();
  $('#contentTextArea').append(modalContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="mdoalTextArea" class="form-control" style="height: 100%;">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>

<textarea name="contents" id="contentTextArea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<button type="button" id="insert" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, but i would suggest that you use `var modalContent = $('#mdoalTextArea').text().trim();
  $('#contentTextArea').val(modalContent);`

Comment: Can you update your snippet to include TinyMCE?  Maybe that's the cause of the issue?  (as above, snippet as-is works fine)

Comment: Why not use TinyMCE to make a Custom button that moves the HTML Content to the Text Area?

Comment: I used TinyMCE command to instert the div text into the text area\ and it wroked